# Any working python mirrors?

Tags: python, windows, ide

Is there anywhere on the web where I can download files needed to setup Python development environment on windows? Trying to learn the language, but everything points to python.org which seems to be down for quite a while.

Comment: If you're trying to get python for windows, it will save you some time to know that most people are still downloading from the 2 series (2.7.2) and you probably want the x86 MSI even if you're on a 64 bit machine.  Here's the DL page.  Had no idea site was down; hope nothing was wrong.  http://python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use the [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/) [mirror of python.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20101223020919/http://www.python.org/).

Here's a [direct link to the Python 3.2.1 installer for windows](http://phihag.de/2011/so/python-3.2.1.msi). Don't forget to check the [checksum](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CqeNbEzJ7PoJ:www.python.org/download/releases/3.2.1/+http://www.python.org/getit/releases/3.2.1&hl=en&strip=1) (MD5: `c148e89b97cd07352c42ecb3bb4f42e2`).

Comment: +1 for a link to the checksum at a trusted source.

Answer (score 1):

[ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) is a alternate Python distribution.

Comment: I don't really get the downvote, activepython is just normal python + stuff. Probably even better for a beginner because it comes with docs.

Answer (score 0):

The mirror I linked before was an old copy. I don't see any current mirrors of python.org.

Instead, you could use the Way Back Machine (archive.org). This is the latest copy from December 2010:

http://web.archive.org/web/20101223020919/http://www.python.org/

Comment: opsrc.org is completely out of date (**last update: 2006**)

Comment: @Grozz Python 2.5 (the newest version there, even as a *beta*) is being deprecated by some projects now. I don't think one should introduce a beginner with a language without native JSON, distinction between bytes and strings, but with old-style classes.

Comment: Sorry about that. Too quick to post. I've updated with a link to browse from the latest archive.org

Comment: So what's the matter with python then?

Comment: *sigh* yes I got that, was trying to access it myself today. My question was with regard to any background information as to why it is down

Comment: @flq [Looks like a hardware problem](https://twitter.com/#!/ThePSF/status/95099018773934080)